# How to store the data to be used in a smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm a new on blockchain so I need your suggestions. I want to write a smart contract to send notifications to the providers for items based on the expiry date (a week ahead). So what's the appropriate way to store the items data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You can store the data on the contract, but its impossible to notify them.

Smart contracts work a lot like APIRests, they won't do anything unless an external call triggers them.

You can't make a function that once it's called it will trigger a timer that will run forever either, since the gas consumption prevents "infinite" logic form happening.

Smart contracts are mean't to be used as a backend to an application, they will server data and logic to the app when their functions are called or when you access its attributes, but they won't do anything by themselves automatically, you need something external to trigger its logic.

You'll have to store the data on the smart contract, and use something else to notify the users, or have the frontend ( your client-side application ) grab all the items for each user when they log-in, and then compare the expiry date with the current date and notify them.

To store the data i would recommend using a mapping of an array of structs ( the struct being the item with its properties ), for example:

```
contract ItemManager {
// We map user addresses to Item arrays, this way, each address has an array of Items assigned to them.
mapping (address => Item[]) public items;

// The structs of the Item.
struct Item {
  string name;
  string description;
  uint256 expiryDate;
}

...

// Emits an event when a new item is added, you can use this to update remote item lists.
event itemAdded(address user, string name, string description, uint256 exipryDate);

...

// Gets the items for the used who called the function
function getItems() public view returns (Item [] memory){
   return items[msg.sender];
}


// Adds an item to the user's Item list who called the function.
function addItem(string memory name, string memory description, uint256 memory expiryDate) public {

    // require the name to not be empty.
    require(bytes(name).length > 0, "name is empty!");

    // require the description to not be empty.
    require(bytes(description).length > 0, "description is empty!");

    // require the expiryDate to not be empty.
    require(bytes(expiryDate).length > 0, "expiryDate is empty!");

    // adds the item to the storage.
    Item newItem = Item(name, description, expiryDate);
    items[msg.sender].push(newItem);

    // emits item added event.
    emit itemAdded(msg.sender, newItem.name, newItem.description, newItem.expiryDate);
}

...

}
```

And then on your frontend, you can check the contracts attributes as such ( example made using web3 ):

```
...
const userItems = await itemManager.methods.items().call();
...
```

NOTE: you can store timestamps (epoch) using the uint256 type, but if you want to store them as strings because its easier for you to parse, then you're free to do so.